# Slow pascal graph unit

Tags: performance, graph, pascal

It's actually my first time in here, so..

What's the problem: standard graph module is too damn slow in drawing.

I have an institute task to make a big program with modules on pascal. Program has several parts but i'm interested in graphical one. I have something like counter (number) in the left corner of the screen and i need it to update fast. But I see every pixel it fills with color, lol.

I'm using Free Pascal 2.6.4.

Asking for some ideas or other ways to draw in a command window fast.

```
program graphical;

uses
        wincrt, graph, querystring, kbd, Timer, sysutils;

const
        speedX1 = 0;
        speedY1 = 0;

var

        //draw part
        gd, gm, error, tw, th, i: integer;
        speedX2: integer = 10;
        speedY2: integer = 10;
        speedSize: word;
        speedImage: pointer;
        size: word;

        //qstring part
        qrec: qstr;
        qtext: AnsiString;
        current, ch: char;

        //keyboard part
        kbrd: kb;

        //speedometer part
        counter: word = 0;
        time: word;
        speed: word;

        //debug part
        c: string;
        t: comp;

procedure draw;  //screens text
begin
        qtext := copy(qrec.text, qrec.qpointer, Length(qrec.text) - qrec.qpointer + 1);
        outTextXY(getMaxX div 2, getMaxY div 8, qtext);
end;

begin
        //graphic initialization
        //gd := detect;
        gd := VGA;
        gm := VGAHi;
        initgraph(gd, gm, '..\bgi');

        //checking for errors
        error := graphResult;
        if (error <> grOk) then
        begin
                writeln('800x600x256 is not supported');
                halt(1);
        end;

        //querystring initialization
        qInit(qrec);
        //keyboard initialization
        initKeyboard(kbrd);
        //timer initialization
        TimerOn;
        time := 0;

        //drawing
        setTextStyle(defaultFont, horizDir, 8);
        draw;
        drawKeyboard(kbrd);
        current := getCurrent(qrec);
        randomize;


        speedX2 := 200;
        speedY2 := 100;

        repeat
                //on timer events
                if (isTimer) then
                begin
                        size := ImageSize(speedX1, speedY1, speedX2, speedY2);
                        GetMem(speedImage, size);
                        GetImage(speedX1, speedY1, speedX2, speedY2, speedImage^);
                        PutImage(speedX1, speedY1, speedImage^, 1);                        FreeMem(speedImage, size);
                        inc(time);
                        speed := round(counter/time/25*60);
                        speed := time;
                        outTextXY(0, 0, IntToStr(speed));


                end;

                if KeyPressed then
                begin
                        ch := readkey;
                        if (ch = #0) then
                                ch := readkey;
                end;


                if (UpCase(ch) = UpCase(current)) then
                begin

                        drawKeyboard(kbrd);
                        draw;
                        current := getCurrent(qrec);
                        inc(counter);
                end
                else
                        if (counter > 0) then
                                dec(counter);

        until (ch = #27) or (getLength(qrec) < 0);

        closegraph;


end.
```

Comment: How about showing some code?

Comment: Ok, but it won't help u, dude.

Comment: ... and formatting it correctly.

Comment: problem is in ontimer part. in theory it updates screen every 40ms, but it doesn't happens 'cause of sloooooow drawing.

Comment: This is not Dos, this is windows console, which is not very suitable for drawing.  You might try wingraph for marginally better performance. For new development, use a technology that is not two decades deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the code:

- `drawKeyboard` is called on each iteration, which might not be necessary
- for each timer event, memory is allocated and released again, which normally is a rather costly operation. The memory needed seems to be of constant size, so try to move allocation and deallocation out of the loop.

Without fixing those, you'd probably have the same problems with other graph libraries too, so give it a try.